# Проблема в адаптации карусели

Tags: css3, html5, адаптивная-верстка, owl-carousel

В обычном состоянии карусель выглядит примерно так. Делала при помощи Owl Carousel:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно выглядеть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При рзрешении > 900 кнопки вылазят за контейнер и "выдавливают" картинки хотя горизонтального скрола нет.

Есть проблема со стилизацией дотс вероятно неправильно прописала в css селекторы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно стоит поменять библиотеку, помогите с решением проблемы
https://saiakune.github.io/Woodies/

https://github.com/saiakune/Woodies

(первый раз пользуюсь данным форумом и не до конца понимаю как правильно задавать вопросы, извините)